# How can a single unit of a business be worth more than its entire market cap?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation, ipo

As of today, June 26th 2019, Thyssenkrupp AG has a market cap of approximately 7.3 billion euros.

On May 10th 2019, Thyssenkrupp AG announced that it will take its elevator business public in an IPO. The elevator and escalator unit is estimated to be worth around 15 billion euros.
On the day of the announcement the stock climbed 28%.

Today, related news saying that Thyssenkrupp may sell the unit cause(d) the stock to achieve massive gains again.

I find this confusing.

How can a single business unit of Thyssenkrupp AG be worth more than the entire publicly listed company? That is, how can the elevator and escalator unit be worth more than twice the market cap of Thyssenkrupp AG?

How do investors benefit from such an IPO or sale? What is it that causes Thyssenkrupp AG to be worth more **after** the IPO? How are the two listings related from an investor's perspective?

Comment: I'm not sure this constitutes a valuable or complete answer, but it seems like the obvious conclusion is that there are other business unit(s) that are *losing* enough money that the balance sheet reflects a total value less than the one unit's value.

Comment: "How can a single business unit of Thyssenkrupp AG be worth more than the entire publicly listed company?"  *Irrational exuberance.*  "I find this confusing." You're not the only one.

Comment: @dwizum Correct.  They may also have debt.

Comment: From the [statistics from Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TKA.DE/key-statistics?p=TKA.DE) it looks like debt indeed reduces Thyssenkrupp's market cap significantly. But even if debt & other business units that lose money pull down Thyssenkrupp's market cap, how would investors benefit from an IPO? Shouldn't the stock price reflect the value of all business units? On the contrary, shouldn't selling the money making business unit in that case drag the stock price of the parent company down?